# I would like to know how I can update the like (heart) based on the id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In the code I have three "posts" (Cards), I would like to handle the like button (heart) seperately for the three posts.
The first post (top Card) has the id 1, second has id 2 and the third has id 3. Right now, the state is the same for all the three cards, should I and can I create a state for each Card?

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';
import Card from './components/card';

export default function App() {

  const [liked, setLiked] = useState();
  
  function onPicLike(id)
  {
    alert(id);

    if(liked){
      setLiked(false);
    } else
    setLiked(true);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.body}>
        <Card image={require('./assets/picture1.png')} liked={liked} id={1} onLike={onPicLike}/>
        <Card image={require('./assets/picture2.png')} liked={liked} id={2} onLike={onPicLike}/>
        <Card image={require('./assets/picture3.png')} liked={liked} id={3} onLike={onPicLike}/>
      </ScrollView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 30 : StatusBar.currentHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#D0CEE2'
  },
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray'
  }
});
```

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-web';

export default function Card({image, liked, id, onLike}) {

    console.log(liked);

  return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() =>onLike(id)}>
                <Image source={image} style={{width: 50, height: 50, resizeMode: 'contain', borderRadius: 20}}/>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <Text style={[{ flex: 1}, styles.actionButtons]}>
              Comment
            </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.actionButtons, {marginRight: 5}]}>
              Like
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>onLike(id)}>
                <FontAwesome name="heart" size={16} color={liked ? "red" : "grey"} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginHorizontal: 50, 
    minHeight: 100, 
    borderRadius: 10, 
    marginVertical: 30,
    padding: 10,
  },
  footer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10
  },
  actionButtons: {
    fontSize: 16
  }
});
```

Comment: Something like this: `<Card ... onLike={() => onPicLike(1)} />`. In `liked` state you hold a structure, e.g. an array, of true/false for each Card: `[false, true, false]` - second is liked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manage that by two approach
-first one by using general state holds the state of three cards and pass it to the cards like that

```
   const [liked, setLiked] = useState({
    1:false,
    2:false,
    3:false
    });
      
      function onPicLike(id)
      {
        alert(id);
          setLiked(prevState=>({...prevState,[id]:!prevState[id]}));
        
      };  
    ......
     <Card image={require('./assets/picture1.png')} liked={liked[1]} id={1} onLike={onPicLike}/>
<Card image={require('./assets/picture1.png')} liked={liked[2]} id={2} onLike={onPicLike}/>
.....
```

- second approach by manage each card state in it's component so you don't need to pass onPickLike function or liked state.

  ```
  export default function Card({image,  id}) {
   const [liked,setLiked] = useState(false) 
     return (
           <View style={styles.card}>
             <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
               <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() =>setLiked(!liked)}>
                   <Image source={image} style={{width: 50, height: 50, resizeMode: 'contain', borderRadius: 20}}/>
               </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.footer}>
               <Text style={[{ flex: 1}, styles.actionButtons]}>
                 Comment
               </Text>
               <Text style={[styles.actionButtons, {marginRight: 5}]}>
                 Like
               </Text>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>setLiked(!liked)}>
                   <FontAwesome name="heart" size={16} color={liked ? "red" : "grey"} />
               </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
           </View>
     );
   }
  ```

Comment: Thanks alot! Second approach worked great, didn't think about that. 

I suppose option one is more clean but I can not get it to work, and I cant really explain why it does not work since I am kinda new to react native and I can't really explain to myself what "setLiked(prevState=>({...prevState,id:!prevState[id]}));" does.

Comment: the first one didn't work because I forgot to wrap the id in setLiked like that [id]
so the funtion will be 
`code`  function onPicLike(id)
      {
        alert(id);
          setLiked(prevState=>({...prevState,[id]:!prevState[id]}));
        
      };   `code`
i edited the first approach it will work now ..
and for setLiked you can pass previous states to make some operations on it and then return the new state and that what i did i talked the previous state and invert the id state from false to true and from true to false
Check React Hooks and things will be easier